# Compute Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Compute Aut$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ up to isomorphism and its order when $p$ is a prime.

I have trouble understanding this homework exercise. Can someone explain what this exercise asks to compute?

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34449/automorphism-group-of-an-abelian-group), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55262/the-automorphism-group-of-a-direct-product-of-abelian-groups-is-isomorphic-to-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know a little linear algebra, you may be familiar with the concept of a vector space. In which consists of an abelian group being acted upon in a certain way by a field.

In this case, we  have that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field and $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}$ is a vector space over this field. Therefore, we can think of an automorphism $\alpha: (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}$ as a linear transformation. Choosing a basis will give you an $n \times n$ matrix, and in order for this to be an automorphism, we must have that the matrix is invertible. This means that all of the columns must be linearly independent.

Here is a concrete example, consider $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2})$. Our matrix will be of the form

$\begin{bmatrix} 
a &b \\
c&d \\
\end{bmatrix}$

for $a,b,c, d \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. In order for the matrix to be invertible, so the first column must not be $[0,0]^{T}$. Therefore, we are left with three choices (4-1) for the first column. For the second column, we must not have it be a scalar multiple of the first column, this leaves us with two choices (4-2) for the second column. In total, we have $6=3 \times 2$ total elements.

Comment: Thank you very much! This a very detailed answer. But now I am stuck when finding the order of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ in general. Is there a systemmatic way to find how many elements are there? I find it hard to count the order when $p$ and $n$ are relatively large.  Thank you!

Comment: I'll get you started, you have $p^{n}-1$ possible entires for the first column. $p^{n}-p$ for the second column. $p^{n}-p^{2}$ entries for the third, and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Fir any group $G$, one can define the group $Aut(G)$ of group automorphisms of $G$. This the functions from $G$ to $G$, one-to-one, onto and that are group morphisms.

This is a group. The question is then, what is this group when $G=(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}})^n$?

The answer should be a group with which you are more familiar (hint : It has something to do with matrices).

Comment: I am unsure of what $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ means exactly. Is it just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Lewis, yes it is.