# Decide Sylow $3$-subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm working on the classification on the group of order 75. Part of its question is to decide the homomorphism between $\Bbb Z_3$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5)$, which is to find the elements in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5)$ with order 3.

Since $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5)\rvert=24\times 20$, it is messy to discuss the Sylow $3$-subgroups based on the order, also, direct computation could do, but it does not seem a good way. I wonder if there's any easier way to determine it.

Comment: The symbol $\ast$ is usually reserved for the *free product* of groups in the context of group theory. Do you mean `$\times$` for $\times$ instead?

Comment: You could use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7FF0BBDD80E8F6BF), I suppose.

Comment: [It appears that $$\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_5)\cong GL_2(\Bbb Z_{5}).$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34449/104041)

Comment: All subgroups of order $3$ are conjugate, so you really only need to find one.  I would recommend using the fact that the automorphism group in question is naturally isomorphic to ${\rm GL}(2,5)$, the multiplicative group of non-singular $2 \times 2$-matrices over the field of order $5$. So you just need to write down a matrix of order $3$ in this group. All such matrices  lie in ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ (determinant $1$), and they have trace $-1$.

Comment: Yes thank you for editting, also the GAP thing is pretty useful and thx for mentioning that! @Shaun

Comment: I think the trace thing is wrong since the identity matrix dose not have trace 1, but this method could work out. @DerekHolt

Comment: I did not say that the identity had trace $1$, I said that elements of order $3$ have trace $-1$. That's because their eigenvalues are $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, where $\omega$ is a cube root of $1$.

Comment: Ohh I got it wrong, that is correct.@DerekHolt