# An abelian group $G$ with ${\rm Aut}(G)$ non-abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Could you give me a simple example of $G$ abelian with ${\rm Aut}(G)$ non-abelian?
Otherwise how could I prove that $G$ abelian implies ${\rm Aut}(G)$ abelian. (I don't really think that's true)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are also examples of *finite* abelian groups with non-abelian automorphism group, e.g.,
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(C_2\times C_2)\cong S_3.
$$
This seems to be the easiest example.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to deduce this result for a generic abelian group?

For example using the decomposition of $G=\mathbb{Z}/p_i^{j}\mathbb{Z} \times .... $
and then show that because $Aut(H\times K)=Aut(H)\times Aut(K)$ (when the orders of both groups have order that are relatively prime) it's possible to find a group that is isomorphic to these $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/p_i^j \mathbb{Z}) \times..$?

Comment: Yes, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34449/automorphism-group-of-an-abelian-group). Here $GL(2,\Bbb F_2)\cong S_3$.

Comment: Also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55262/the-automorphism-group-of-a-direct-product-of-abelian-groups-is-isomorphic-to-a/55275#55275).

Answer (score 11):

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$ its automorphism group $Gl(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is not commutative.